# Accessing HTML elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to pass parameters from a PHP to a JavaScript, and this is the way I do this:

my `php` file:

```
<div>
    <textarea name="text" cols="80" rows="2">
     <?= $note['note'] ?>
    </textarea>
    <p type="hidden" name="request_id" value="<?= $request_id ?>" >
    <p type="hidden" name="cve" value="<?= $cve ?>" >
    <p type="hidden" name="note_id" value="<?= $note['note_id'] ?>" >
    <p type="hidden" name="status" value="<?= $note['status'] ?>" >
    <button class="add-note">Save</button>  
</div>
```

My `JavaScript` function:

```
$(function() {
    $(".add-note").click(function(){
        tr = $(this).parent();
        tds = tr.children();
        note = $(tds[0]).text();
        request_id = $(tds[1]).value;
        cve = $(tds[2]).value;
        note_id = $(tds[3]).value;
        status = $(tds[4]).value;
        alert(note);
    });
});
```

The result is I get the value `Save` when I get the text of `note`, that is, the text of the buttom itself, instead of the text placed in the textarea. I get nothing for the rest of the values.

I wanted to approach this with a classic form, but the thing is that I need the current value of a textarea, that why I am using JavaScript, but I am not accessing properly to the HTML elements...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your `p` tags are unclosed, so this must create the wrong structure. I also think you want to replace the `p` tags with `<input type="hidden" />`...

Comment: I agree with @somethinghere and also consider to use **var** for the variable in javascript. Es. var tr = $(this).ciao(); var tds = tr.miao;

Comment: @Vixed Maybe even use some better variable names - this is really confusing. We are no longer in the nineties where every byte was so precious :)

Comment: @somethinghere I was talking about it just a week ago on linkedin: [take a look here](https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?activity=6104007324379156480)

Comment: Yeah, I used input because the `value` of `p` wouldn't work like that, with the `input` it does.

I also used `.val()` for extracting the text of the `textarea`element and it works perfectly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    <textarea name="text" cols="80" rows="2" id="texta">
     <?= $note['note'] ?>
    </textarea>
    <p type="hidden" name="request_id" id="request_id" value="<?= $request_id ?>" >
    <p type="hidden" name="cve" id="cve" value="<?= $cve ?>" >
    <p type="hidden" name="note_id" id="note_id" value="<?= $note['note_id'] ?>" >
    <p type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="<?= $note['status'] ?>" >
    <button class="add-note">Save</button>  
</div>  

 $(function() {
    $(".add-note").click(function(){
        note = $('#texta').val();
        request_id = $('#request_id'.val();
        cve = $('#cve').val();
        note_id = $('#note_id').val();
        status = $('#status').val();
        alert(note);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of value use data-xx properties meant exactly for that

```
  <p type="hidden" name="request_id" data-request="<?= $request_id ?>" >
```

and extract using

```
request_id = $(tds[1]).data('request');
```